# How to get verbose on reboot/shutdown on Arch?

Tags: arch-linux, configuration, reboot

I am using Arch Linux for a while, when I reboot my system it takes more than expected.

I remember changing some configuration file to avoid this issue, but without the information on what is going on and only getting `The system will reboot...`, I can't debug the issue properly.

How I can change the verbosity on the reboot/shutdown to get all of the information on what is my system doing?

Comment: Are you using LVM?

Comment: How do I know if I'm using LVM? I have used the archinstall script for the installation